# Proxy trap for a part of functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-proxy

I implemented a proxy handler to intercept all functions in a class.

```
class SBFinder {
  foo1({ name, id }) {
    console.log(name + id);
  }

  foo2({ name, id }) {
    console.log(id + name);
  }
}

const handler = {
  get(target, propKey, receiver) {
    const targetValue = Reflect.get(target, propKey, receiver);
    if (typeof targetValue === 'function') {
      return (...args) => {
        console.log('before');
        const res = targetValue.apply(this, args);
        console.log('after');
        return res;
      };
    }

    return targetValue;
  },
};

const finderProxy = new Proxy(new SBFinder(), handler);
finderProxy.foo1({ name: 'name1', id: 223 });
```

Now I want the handler to be applied only to a part of funstions. I understand that it's quite easy to implement according to a function name, number of arguments etc.
But I don't want to limit the user by a naming conventions. Is there a way to do it for example according to some JSDocs tag (like we do with annotations in java). Or maybe there's another practice you can advice?

Comment: No, JSDocs comments are not accessible from code. You might be looking for decorators instead.

Answer (score 0):

can you be more specific in what you want to do?

In your `get` handler you are getting the class methods ("functions") but you should not call the function here.

if you return a wrapper function then you should make sure that you bind the correct object (which is the `target` not `this`) and you will want some logic to evaluate the args or the method name.

The desired method name is what you have referred to a `propKey`. So you could have some logic that examines propKey.

Protip -- if you are going to do tests against the value of propKey then watch out that propKey could be a `symbol` so you might have to add a check for when propKey is a `string` (e.g. a regex test will auto-cast to string)

Note also that you could return a proxy for the function also like this:

```js
const fnProxyMaker = (fn)=>new Proxy( fn, { 
   apply(target, that, args){
       // do something before calling or whatever
      return target(...args);
   }
});

const handler = {
  get(target, propKey, receiver) {
    const targetValue = Reflect.get(target, propKey, receiver);
    if (typeof targetValue === 'function' && propKey === 'foo1') {
      return fnProxyMaker(targetValue)
    }

    return targetValue;
  },
};
```

or define the methods as proxies in the class:

```js
class SBFinder {
  constructor(){
     ['foo1','foo2'].forEach(method=>
        Object.defineProperty(this, method, {
         get : fnProxyMaker( ({name,id})=>console.log(name+id) )
      }), this )
  }
}
```